# Can I safely include "self-defined" HTML Tags in a HTML Website?

Tags: html, tags

I have seen a website that has a doctype of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This website uses HTML Tags that I have never seen before like `<section>`.

My Question:

1.) Is this kind of "generic Doctype" recommended for a normal website? (I've never seen this this before, what are the pro and cons?)

2.) When is it valid to use such "self defined" HTML Tags? Is this valid with this doctype Declaration?

Comment: This book may be of use: http://diveintohtml5.org/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the doctype for HTML 5.

1. You are safe to use this Doctype as it won't break older browsers and modern browsers will understand it.
2. This is a valid tag for HTML 5. If you really want custom tags, you'd need to create a custom doctype for your document to reference, but that's [discouraged](http://www.w3.org/Style/customdtd).